# How to forcs Highcharts yAxis label to show 2 decimal points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating a chart with some labels rendered directly onto the yAxis. These labels have 2 decimal points in them and get truncated, because the yAxis automatic labels don't have the same format.

You can see from the picture below that the colored labels in the yAxis are being truncated.

[image]

Is there any way of forcing the yAxis labels to have 2 decimal points?

Here is a fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/stuhqfd5/

And here is the code:

```
function toLocaleFloat(value, noDecimals = 2, ifEmpty = '') {
  if (!value)
    return ifEmpty;
  else
    return parseFloat(value).toLocaleString(undefined, {
      minimumFractionDigits: noDecimals,
      maximumFractionDigits: noDecimals
    })
}

function renderPriceLabelsInYAxis() {
  var chart = this;

  if (chart.axes.length > 1) {
    if (chart.myLabels) {
      chart.myLabels.forEach(function(label) {
        label.destroy();
      });
    }
    chart.myLabels = [];

    if (chart.series && chart.series.length > 0) {
      chart.series.reverse().forEach(function(series) {
        if (series.options.mssDisplayPriceInAxis && series.data.length > 0) {
          let data = series.data[series.data.length - 1];
          chart.myLabel = chart.renderer.label(toLocaleFloat(data.y), chart.axes[1].width + chart.axes[1].left + chart.plotLeft + 2, data.plotY + chart.plotTop - 9)
            .attr({
              fill: series.color,
              zIndex: series.options.mssDisplayPriceInAxisZIndex ? series.options.mssDisplayPriceInAxisZIndex : 1000
            }).css({
              "font-size": '0.8rem',
              color: 'white',
              "border": "1ps solid black",
              "border-radius": "10px",
            })
            .add(chart.labelGroup);
          chart.myLabels.push(chart.myLabel);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

let options = {
  "mssChartType": "valuation",
  "mssData": ["Sales per share", "P/Sales"],
  "chart": {
    "style": {
      "fontFamily": "\u0027Helvetica Neue\u0027, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
    },
    "events": {
      render: renderPriceLabelsInYAxis
    }
  },
  "title": {
    "enabled": true,
    "text": "Microsoft Corporation",
    "align": "left"
  },
  "subtitle": {
    "enabled": true,
    "text": "Price Forecast based on future Sales per share",
    "align": "left"
  },
  "exporting": null,
  "legend": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "rangeSelector": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "xAxis": [{
    "type": "datetime",
    "crosshair": {
      "color": "#555",
      "snap": true,
      "zIndex": 100,
      "dashStyle": "dash",
      "label": {
        "enabled": true,
        "backgroundColor": "#666"
      }
    },
    "opposite": false,
    "ordinal": false,
    "labels": {
      "format": "{value:%Y}"
    },
    "gridLineWidth": 1,
    "tickPositions": [1530316800000, 1561852800000, 1593475200000, 1625011200000, 1656547200000, 1688083200000, 1719705600000, 1751241600000, 1782777600000],
    "units": [
      ["year", [1]]
    ]
  }],
  "yAxis": [{
    "left": 0,
    "crosshair": {
      "color": "#555",
      "snap": false,
      "zIndex": 100,
      "dashStyle": "dash",
      "label": {
        "enabled": true,
        "format": "{value:.2f}",
        "backgroundColor": "#666"
      }
    },
    "opposite": true,
    "min": 0,
    "title": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "labels": {
      "align": "left"
    }
  }],
  "tooltip": {
    "enabled": true,
    "animation": false,
    "formatterType": "Valuation",
    "backgroundColor": "#666",
    "useHTML": true,
    "shared": false,
    "style": {
      "color": "#fff"
    }
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "animation": false,
      "allowPointSelect": false,
      "threshold": null,
      "states": {
        "hover": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "inactive": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "select": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      },
      "turboThreshold": 13000
    },
    "area": {
      "animation": false,
      "threshold": 411.65,
      "marker": {
        "enabled": false
      }
    },
    "areaspline": {
      "animation": false,
      "threshold": null,
      "marker": {
        "radius": 2,
        "fillColor": "#000",
        "symbol": "circle",
        "enabled": true
      }
    },
    "spline": {
      "animation": false,
      "threshold": null,
      "marker": {
        "enabled": false
      }
    },
    "line": {
      "animation": false,
      "threshold": null
    }
  },
  "series": [{
    "tooltip": {
      "enabled": false,
      "animation": false
    },
    "zIndex": 101,
    "type": "line",
    "name": "Price",
    "color": "#000",
    "data": [
      [1530748800000, 99.76],
      [1531353600000, 104.19],
      [1531958400000, 104.4],
      [1532563200000, 109.62],
      [1533168000000, 107.57],
      [1533772800000, 109.67],
      [1534377600000, 107.64],
      [1534982400000, 107.56],
      [1535587200000, 111.95],
      [1536192000000, 108.74],
      [1536796800000, 112.91],
      [1537401600000, 113.57],
      [1538006400000, 114.41],
      [1538611200000, 112.79],
      [1539216000000, 105.91],
      [1539820800000, 108.5],
      [1540425600000, 108.3],
      [1541030400000, 105.92],
      [1541635200000, 111.75],
      [1542240000000, 107.28],
      [1542758400000, 103.11],
      [1543449600000, 110.19],
      [1544054400000, 109.19],
      [1544659200000, 109.45],
      [1545264000000, 101.51],
      [1545868800000, 101.18],
      [1546473600000, 97.4],
      [1547078400000, 103.6],
      [1547683200000, 106.12],
      [1548288000000, 106.2],
      [1548892800000, 104.43],
      [1549497600000, 105.27],
      [1550102400000, 106.9],
      [1550707200000, 109.41],
      [1551312000000, 112.03],
      [1551916800000, 110.39],
      [1552521600000, 114.59],
      [1553126400000, 120.22],
      [1553731200000, 116.93],
      [1554336000000, 119.36],
      [1554940800000, 120.33],
      [1555545600000, 123.37],
      [1556150400000, 129.15],
      [1556755200000, 126.21],
      [1557360000000, 125.5],
      [1557964800000, 128.93],
      [1558569600000, 126.18],
      [1559174400000, 125.73],
      [1559779200000, 127.82],
      [1560384000000, 132.32],
      [1560988800000, 136.95],
      [1561593600000, 134.15],
      [1562112000000, 137.46],
      [1562803200000, 138.4],
      [1563408000000, 136.42],
      [1564012800000, 140.19],
      [1564617600000, 138.06],
      [1565222400000, 138.89],
      [1565827200000, 133.68],
      [1566432000000, 137.78],
      [1567036800000, 138.12],
      [1567641600000, 140.05],
      [1568246400000, 137.52],
      [1568851200000, 141.07],
      [1569456000000, 139.54],
      [1570060800000, 136.28],
      [1570665600000, 139.1],
      [1571270400000, 139.69],
      [1571875200000, 139.94],
      [1572480000000, 143.37],
      [1573084800000, 144.26],
      [1573689600000, 148.06],
      [1574294400000, 149.48],
      [1574812800000, 152.32],
      [1575504000000, 149.93],
      [1576108800000, 153.24],
      [1576713600000, 155.71],
      [1577318400000, 158.67],
      [1577923200000, 160.62],
      [1578528000000, 162.09],
      [1579132800000, 166.17],
      [1579737600000, 166.72],
      [1580342400000, 172.78],
      [1580947200000, 183.63],
      [1581552000000, 183.71],
      [1582156800000, 184.42],
      [1582761600000, 158.18],
      [1583366400000, 166.27],
      [1583971200000, 139.06],
      [1584576000000, 142.71],
      [1585180800000, 156.11],
      [1585785600000, 155.26],
      [1586390400000, 165.14],
      [1586995200000, 177.04],
      [1587600000000, 171.42],
      [1588204800000, 179.21],
      [1588809600000, 183.6],
      [1589414400000, 180.53],
      [1590019200000, 183.43],
      [1590624000000, 181.4],
      [1591228800000, 182.92],
      [1591833600000, 186.27],
      [1592438400000, 196.32],
      [1593043200000, 200.34],
      [1593648000000, 206.26],
      [1594252800000, 214.32],
      [1594857600000, 203.92],
      [1595462400000, 202.54],
      [1596067200000, 203.9],
      [1596672000000, 216.35],
      [1597276800000, 208.7],
      [1597881600000, 214.58],
      [1598486400000, 226.58],
      [1599091200000, 217.3],
      [1599696000000, 205.37],
      [1600300800000, 202.91],
      [1600905600000, 203.19],
      [1601510400000, 212.46],
      [1602115200000, 210.58],
      [1602720000000, 219.66],
      [1603324800000, 214.89],
      [1603929600000, 204.72],
      [1604534400000, 223.29],
      [1605139200000, 215.44],
      [1605744000000, 212.42],
      [1606262400000, 213.87],
      [1606953600000, 214.24],
      [1607558400000, 210.52],
      [1608163200000, 219.42],
      [1608768000000, 222.75],
      [1609372800000, 222.42],
      [1609977600000, 218.29],
      [1610582400000, 213.02],
      [1611187200000, 224.97],
      [1611792000000, 238.93],
      [1612396800000, 242.01],
      [1613001600000, 244.49],
      [1613606400000, 243.79],
      [1614211200000, 228.99],
      [1614816000000, 226.73],
      [1615420800000, 237.13],
      [1616025600000, 230.72],
      [1616630400000, 232.34],
      [1617235200000, 242.35],
      [1617840000000, 253.25],
      [1618444800000, 259.5],
      [1619049600000, 257.17],
      [1619654400000, 252.51],
      [1620259200000, 249.73],
      [1620864000000, 243.03],
      [1621468800000, 246.48],
      [1622073600000, 249.31],
      [1622678400000, 245.71],
      [1623283200000, 257.24],
      [1623888000000, 260.9],
      [1624492800000, 266.69],
      [1625097600000, 271.6],
      [1625702400000, 277.42],
      [1626307200000, 281.03],
      [1626912000000, 286.14],
      [1627516800000, 286.5],
      [1628121600000, 289.52],
      [1628726400000, 289.81],
      [1629331200000, 296.77],
      [1629936000000, 299.09],
      [1630540800000, 301.15],
      [1631145600000, 297.25],
      [1631750400000, 305.22],
      [1632355200000, 299.56],
      [1632960000000, 281.92],
      [1633564800000, 294.85],
      [1634169600000, 302.75],
      [1634774400000, 310.76],
      [1635379200000, 324.35],
      [1635984000000, 336.44],
      [1636588800000, 332.43],
      [1637193600000, 341.27],
      [1637712000000, 337.91],
      [1638403200000, 329.49],
      [1639008000000, 333.1],
      [1639612800000, 324.9],
      [1640217600000, 334.69],
      [1640822400000, 339.32],
      [1641427200000, 313.88],
      [1642032000000, 304.8],
      [1642636800000, 301.6],
      [1643241600000, 299.84],
      [1643846400000, 301.25],
      [1644451200000, 302.38],
      [1645056000000, 290.73],
      [1645660800000, 294.59],
      [1646265600000, 295.92],
      [1646870400000, 285.59],
      [1647475200000, 295.22],
      [1648080000000, 304.1],
      [1648684800000, 308.31],
      [1649289600000, 301.37],
      [1649894400000, 279.83],
      [1650499200000, 280.81],
      [1651104000000, 289.63],
      [1651708800000, 277.35],
      [1652313600000, 255.35],
      [1652918400000, 253.14],
      [1653523200000, 265.9],
      [1654128000000, 274.58],
      [1654732800000, 264.79],
      [1655337600000, 244.97],
      [1655942400000, 258.86],
      [1656547200000, 256.83],
      [1657152000000, 268.4],
      [1657756800000, 254.08],
      [1658361600000, 264.84],
      [1658966400000, 276.41],
      [1659571200000, 283.65],
      [1660176000000, 287.02],
      [1660780800000, 290.17],
      [1661385600000, 278.85],
      [1661990400000, 260.4],
      [1662595200000, 258.52],
      [1663200000000, 245.38],
      [1663804800000, 240.98],
      [1664409600000, 237.5],
      [1665014400000, 246.79],
      [1665619200000, 234.24],
      [1666224000000, 236.15],
      [1666828800000, 226.75],
      [1667433600000, 214.25],
      [1668038400000, 242.98],
      [1668643200000, 241.68],
      [1669161600000, 247.58],
      [1669852800000, 254.69],
      [1670457600000, 247.4],
      [1671062400000, 249.01],
      [1671667200000, 238.19],
      [1672272000000, 241.01],
      [1672876800000, 222.31],
      [1673481600000, 238.51],
      [1674086400000, 231.93],
      [1674691200000, 248],
      [1675296000000, 264.6],
      [1675900800000, 263.62],
      [1676505600000, 262.15],
      [1677110400000, 254.77],
      [1677715200000, 251.11],
      [1678320000000, 252.32],
      [1678924800000, 276.2],
      [1679529600000, 277.66],
      [1680134400000, 284.05],
      [1680739200000, 291.6],
      [1681344000000, 289.84],
      [1681948800000, 286.11],
      [1682553600000, 304.83],
      [1683158400000, 305.41],
      [1683763200000, 310.11],
      [1684368000000, 318.52],
      [1684972800000, 325.92],
      [1685577600000, 332.58],
      [1686182400000, 325.26],
      [1686787200000, 348.1],
      [1687392000000, 339.71],
      [1687996800000, 335.05],
      [1688601600000, 341.27],
      [1689206400000, 342.66],
      [1689811200000, 346.87],
      [1690416000000, 330.72],
      [1691020800000, 326.66],
      [1691625600000, 322.93],
      [1692230400000, 316.88],
      [1692835200000, 319.97],
      [1693440000000, 327.76],
      [1694044800000, 329.91],
      [1694649600000, 338.7],
      [1695254400000, 319.53],
      [1695859200000, 313.64],
      [1696464000000, 319.36],
      [1697068800000, 331.16],
      [1697673600000, 331.32],
      [1698278400000, 327.89],
      [1698883200000, 348.32],
      [1699488000000, 360.69],
      [1700092800000, 376.17],
      [1700611200000, 377.85],
      [1701302400000, 378.91],
      [1701907200000, 370.95],
      [1702512000000, 365.93],
      [1703116800000, 373.54],
      [1703721600000, 375.28],
      [1704326400000, 367.94],
      [1704931200000, 384.63],
      [1705536000000, 393.87],
      [1706140800000, 404.87],
      [1706745600000, 403.78],
      [1707350400000, 414.11],
      [1707955200000, 406.56],
      [1708560000000, 411.65]
    ],
    "mssSeriesType": "MyStockValue"
  }, {
    "zIndex": 100,
    "type": "areaspline",
    "name": "Bull Case",
    "color": "rgba(175, 225, 175, 1)",
    "data": [{
      "x": 1530316800000,
      "y": 256.147164,
      "ps": 14.1596,
      "pm": 18.09,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1561852800000,
      "y": 293.627835,
      "ps": 16.2315,
      "pm": 18.09,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1593475200000,
      "y": 336.734496,
      "ps": 18.6144,
      "pm": 18.09,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1625011200000,
      "y": 399.67141499999997,
      "ps": 22.0935,
      "pm": 18.09,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1656547200000,
      "y": 475.689213,
      "ps": 26.2957,
      "pm": 18.09,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1688083200000,
      "y": 513.054108,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 18.09,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }],
    "zoneAxis": "x",
    "mssSeriesType": "MyStockValueAverage",
    "mssMyStockValueMetricAverage": 18.09,
    "mssMyStockValueMetricName": "Sales per share"
  }, {
    "mssDisplayPriceInAxis": true,
    "mssDisplayPriceInAxisZIndex": 1000,
    "marker": {
      "radius": 2,
      "fillColor": "#000",
      "symbol": "circle",
      "enabled": true
    },
    "zIndex": 100,
    "type": "line",
    "name": "Bull Case",
    "color": "rgba(175, 225, 175, 1)",
    "data": [{
      "x": 1708646400000,
      "y": 410.34,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 18.09,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1719705600000,
      "y": 513.054108,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 18.09,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1751241600000,
      "y": 513.054108,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 18.09,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1782777600000,
      "y": 513.054108,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 18.09,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }],
    "lineWidth": 3,
    "zoneAxis": "x",
    "mssSeriesType": "MyStockValueAverage",
    "mssMyStockValueMetricAverage": 18.09,
    "mssMyStockValueMetricName": "Sales per share"
  }, {
    "zIndex": 100,
    "type": "areaspline",
    "name": "Base",
    "color": "rgba(126, 182, 235, 1)",
    "data": [{
      "x": 1530316800000,
      "y": 204.889412,
      "ps": 14.1596,
      "pm": 14.47,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1561852800000,
      "y": 234.869805,
      "ps": 16.2315,
      "pm": 14.47,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1593475200000,
      "y": 269.350368,
      "ps": 18.6144,
      "pm": 14.47,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1625011200000,
      "y": 319.692945,
      "ps": 22.0935,
      "pm": 14.47,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1656547200000,
      "y": 380.498779,
      "ps": 26.2957,
      "pm": 14.47,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1688083200000,
      "y": 410.386564,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 14.47,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }],
    "zoneAxis": "x",
    "mssSeriesType": "MyStockValueAverage",
    "mssMyStockValueMetricAverage": 14.47,
    "mssMyStockValueMetricName": "Sales per share"
  }, {
    "mssDisplayPriceInAxis": true,
    "mssDisplayPriceInAxisZIndex": 1000,
    "marker": {
      "radius": 2,
      "fillColor": "#000",
      "symbol": "circle",
      "enabled": true
    },
    "zIndex": 100,
    "type": "line",
    "name": "Base",
    "color": "rgba(126, 182, 235, 1)",
    "data": [{
      "x": 1708646400000,
      "y": 410.34,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 14.47,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1719705600000,
      "y": 410.386564,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 14.47,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1751241600000,
      "y": 410.386564,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 14.47,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1782777600000,
      "y": 410.386564,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 14.47,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }],
    "lineWidth": 3,
    "zoneAxis": "x",
    "mssSeriesType": "MyStockValueAverage",
    "mssMyStockValueMetricAverage": 14.47,
    "mssMyStockValueMetricName": "Sales per share"
  }, {
    "zIndex": 100,
    "type": "areaspline",
    "name": "Analysts",
    "color": "rgba(255, 172, 28, 1)",
    "data": [{
      "x": 1530316800000,
      "y": 172.88871600000002,
      "ps": 14.1596,
      "pm": 12.21,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1561852800000,
      "y": 198.18661500000002,
      "ps": 16.2315,
      "pm": 12.21,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1593475200000,
      "y": 227.281824,
      "ps": 18.6144,
      "pm": 12.21,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1625011200000,
      "y": 269.761635,
      "ps": 22.0935,
      "pm": 12.21,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1656547200000,
      "y": 321.07049700000005,
      "ps": 26.2957,
      "pm": 12.21,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1688083200000,
      "y": 346.290252,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 12.21,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }],
    "zoneAxis": "x",
    "mssSeriesType": "MyStockValueAverage",
    "mssMyStockValueMetricAverage": 12.21,
    "mssMyStockValueMetricName": "Sales per share"
  }, {
    "mssDisplayPriceInAxis": true,
    "mssDisplayPriceInAxisZIndex": 999,
    "marker": {
      "radius": 2,
      "fillColor": "#000",
      "symbol": "circle",
      "enabled": true
    },
    "zIndex": 100,
    "type": "line",
    "name": "Analysts",
    "color": "rgba(255, 172, 28, 1)",
    "data": [{
      "x": 1708646400000,
      "y": 410.34,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 12.21,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1719705600000,
      "y": 401.38614613518354,
      "ps": 32.87355824202977,
      "pm": 12.21,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1751241600000,
      "y": 458.85191043417655,
      "ps": 37.5800090445681,
      "pm": 12.21,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }],
    "lineWidth": 3,
    "zoneAxis": "x",
    "mssSeriesType": "MyStockValueAverage",
    "mssMyStockValueMetricAverage": 12.21,
    "mssMyStockValueMetricName": "Sales per share"
  }, {
    "zIndex": 100,
    "type": "areaspline",
    "name": "Bear Case",
    "color": "rgba(240, 128, 128, 1)",
    "data": [{
      "x": 1530316800000,
      "y": 153.63165999999998,
      "ps": 14.1596,
      "pm": 10.85,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1561852800000,
      "y": 176.111775,
      "ps": 16.2315,
      "pm": 10.85,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1593475200000,
      "y": 201.96624,
      "ps": 18.6144,
      "pm": 10.85,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1625011200000,
      "y": 239.714475,
      "ps": 22.0935,
      "pm": 10.85,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1656547200000,
      "y": 285.308345,
      "ps": 26.2957,
      "pm": 10.85,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1688083200000,
      "y": 307.71902,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 10.85,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }],
    "zoneAxis": "x",
    "mssSeriesType": "MyStockValueAverage",
    "mssMyStockValueMetricAverage": 10.85,
    "mssMyStockValueMetricName": "Sales per share"
  }, {
    "mssDisplayPriceInAxis": true,
    "mssDisplayPriceInAxisZIndex": 1000,
    "marker": {
      "radius": 2,
      "fillColor": "#000",
      "symbol": "circle",
      "enabled": true
    },
    "zIndex": 100,
    "type": "line",
    "name": "Bear Case",
    "color": "rgba(240, 128, 128, 1)",
    "data": [{
      "x": 1708646400000,
      "y": 410.34,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 10.85,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1719705600000,
      "y": 307.71902,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 10.85,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1751241600000,
      "y": 307.71902,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 10.85,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }, {
      "x": 1782777600000,
      "y": 307.71902,
      "ps": 28.3612,
      "pm": 10.85,
      "fu": "Sales per share",
      "pu": "P/Sales"
    }],
    "lineWidth": 3,
    "zoneAxis": "x",
    "mssSeriesType": "MyStockValueAverage",
    "mssMyStockValueMetricAverage": 10.85,
    "mssMyStockValueMetricName": "Sales per share"
  }, {
    "marker": {
      "radius": 2,
      "fillColor": "#000",
      "symbol": "circle",
      "enabled": true
    },
    "zIndex": 100,
    "type": "line",
    "name": "Risk Free",
    "color": "#aaa",
    "data": [{
      "x": 1708560000000,
      "y": 411.65
    }, {
      "x": 1782777600000,
      "y": 475.1981551598399
    }],
    "lineWidth": 3,
    "zoneAxis": "x",
    "mssSeriesType": "MyStockValueAverage",
    "mssMyStockValueMetricName": "Sales per share"
  }],
  "annotations": [{
    "draggable": "",
    "labelOptions": {
      "align": "center",
      "style": {
        "fontSize": "0.6rem"
      }
    },
    "labels": [],
    "shapes": []
  }],
  "colors": ["#51b5ce", "#89c733", "#2f7ed8", "#0d233a", "#8b7a21", "#54a329", "#910000", "#1aadce", "#492970", "#f28f43", "#77a1a1", "#c42525", "#a6c96a"]
};

Highcharts.chart('container', options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding marginRight to the chart object, so it looks like this:

```
"chart": {
    "marginRight": 50,
    "style": {
      "fontFamily": "\u0027Helvetica Neue\u0027, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
    },
    "events": {
       render: renderPriceLabelsInYAxis
    
}
```

Not a perfect solution, but it will do for now.